# Custom finder that returns a list when I do a toArray in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I know how to write a custom finder in CakePHP 3.x by looking at [this](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-find-methods).

I also know how to get a "list" by using `find('list')` and then use `toArray` via [this](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs)

What I want to do is to write a custom finder that will ensure that I can use `toArray` on the result of the custom finder and get back a similar array if I use `find('list')`.

My custom finder method name is `findListForDynamicViews`.

Hence I want

```
 $query = $circlesTable->find('listForDynamicViews');
 $data = $query->toArray(); // this gives me an associative array similar to the one we get from find('list')
```

How do I write the custom finder given that I know how to use `where()` for the query?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly, maybe you just want to do what `Table::findList()` does, ie use `Query::formatResults()`? **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/a64a62126287abbc3d8c53f48a5281ac77e791b0/src/ORM/Table.php#L897**

Comment: What I meant was, do I need to do something special inside the custom finder? Like I need to set the select() in a special way?

Comment: Hey ndm, you are right. You gave me exactly what I needed. Do you want to write an answer, so I can accept it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using result formatters, which is what the `list` finder does too:

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/a64a62126287abbc3d8c53f48a5281ac77e791b0/src/ORM/Table.php#L897**

Stripped to the bare essentials, you simply combine by key and value fields, which are usually the primary key and the display field:

```
$query->formatResults(function(\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface $results) {
    return $results->combine('key_field', 'value_field');
});
```

Comment: Small note for the other slow / poor readers:  that "return" is in an anonymous function, you still need to return the Query object at the end of the finder.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this short code will work in your case:

```
$query = $circlesTable->find('list')->find('listForDynamicViews');
```

Yo do not need to modify your custom finder at all.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with a custom finder like this:

```
// contained in my PropertiesTable.php
public function findCityList(Query $query) {
    return $query->find('list', ['keyField' => 'id', 'valueField' =>'city'])
                ->select(['city'])->distinct(['city']);
}
```

The call to list on find() already returns an array so you wouldnt need to call toArray() after it.

```
// the retuning array 
$citys = [
    '7' => 'Olímpia',
    '10' => 'São José do Rio Preto',
    '17' => 'Guarujá'
];
```

Hope it helps.